# Spring boot starts in SSL by default

Tags: java, spring-boot

For some reason, Spring Boot is starting in SSL by default.  I have an unmodified project from Spring Initializr with only web dependency and an empty application.properties.  When I start this from the command line it fails with `SSL is enabled but no trust material is configured`.

How can I return this to normal behavior of non-SSL?

**Steps taken since orignal posting**

1. delete mvn cache in .m2 directory - same failure
2. Delete jdk and unzip fresh copy - same failure
3. switch to the WSL platform, install JDK-17 - **success**

**Conclusion**

- Something's corrupted in Windows 11

**Next steps**

- Reset Windows 11 leaving my data intact

*Original question files below*

pom.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>demo</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>17</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

application.properties

```
 is empty
```

DemoApplication.java

```java
    package com.example.demo;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class DemoApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        }

    }
```

src/main/resources

[image: src/main/resources]  Both static and templates directories are empty

output from terminal

```
> .\mvnw clean spring-boot:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------------< com.example:demo >--------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ demo ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\user\Downloads\demo\demo\target
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot:3.1.0:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ demo >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ demo ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO] Copying 0 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :source
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file with javac [debug release 17] to target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ demo ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\user\Downloads\demo\demo\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :dependency
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file with javac [debug release 17] to target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot:3.1.0:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ demo <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot:3.1.0:run (default-cli) @ demo ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.0)

2023-06-19T11:39:04.545-05:00  INFO 13672 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.7 with PID 13672 (C:\Users\user\Downloads\demo\demo\target\classes started by user in C:\Users\user\Downloads\demo\demo)
2023-06-19T11:39:04.549-05:00  INFO 13672 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-06-19T11:39:05.110-05:00  WARN 13672 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
2023-06-19T11:39:05.116-05:00  INFO 13672 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-19T11:39:05.127-05:00 ERROR 13672 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:602) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SSL is enabled but no trust material is configured
        at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerSslBundle.createStoreBundle(WebServerSslBundle.java:165) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerSslBundle.get(WebServerSslBundle.java:154) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.server.AbstractConfigurableWebServerFactory.getSslBundle(AbstractConfigurableWebServerFactory.java:216) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.customizeSsl(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:367) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.customizeConnector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:344) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:203) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        ... 8 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.955 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-06-19T11:39:05-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.1.0:run (default-cli) on project demo: Process terminated with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: What else do you have in scr/main/resources?

Comment: two empty directories static and templates that were created by Spring Initializr.  Question updated with image

Comment: Very strange. mvn clean don't help?

Comment: fails with same error.  replaced output above with mvn clean spring-boot:run

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit like killing a mosquito with explosives but resetting Windows 11 worked.  At least I didn't have to reload my data.